# Showing a single loadingscreen for multiple events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My app downloads from several URLs at the same time. Non of them finishes at the same time, but i only want one loading screen letting the user see that something is going on :-)

I've tried a "ticket" system, where i have a List<>. Each event that triggers a download add a ticket to the list. When they are done they remove one.
I've then have a BackgroundWorker running every 200ms that checks this list. If the list count is 0 and the loadingscreen (UserControl) exists (busyscreen.GetType().Name comparison to every  object in this.LayoutRoot.Children) it removes the child. 
If the list isnt 0 and there is no child name busyscreen it gets added.

What's wrong with this logic? I cant seem to get it to work, is there a better way to do this kind of work?

Comment: Seems fine to me (I'd probably use a timer instead of a background worker, but that's a minor detail)... what happens when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you want to use blocking and something like WaitHandle- you can make your code block until signalled to proceed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx

Basically, you create an array of ManualResetEvent objects - these objects will signal to the main thread when the work is done

Then you call

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(arrayOfManualResetEvents)
```

which will block until the reset events are signalled

```
ManualResetEvent.Set()
```

So in pseudocode:

```
> Create each URL loader
> Create a ManualResetEvent for each loader
> Start each loader loading
> Call WaitHandle.WaitAll(arrayOfManualResets) which will block on your main thread
> In each URL LoadComplete handler call the associated ManualResetEvent.Set()
> The main thread will continue when all are signalled
```

**Edit:** As has been pointed out - WaitHandle.WaitAll doesn't work on Windows Phone. There's an alternative to it here:

[Alternatives for WaitHandle.WaitAll on Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206520/alternatives-for-waithandle-waitall-on-windows-phone)

Which seems like it would do the job. Consider using it because I always find that code that ideally should block, when used with timers **can** work but is more fiddly and prone to bugs

Comment: Ah, well that puts a stop to that then!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Singleton` object that will contain `LoadCount` property and loadCount field (of course do not forget about `INotifyProeprtyChanged`) which you can use further as you need. When you start downloading from new URL do something like `Interlocked.Increment(ref loadCount);` and on callback - `Interlocked.Decrement(ref loadCount);`.
 Depending on `LoadCount` you can show "loading screen".